# How to set a transition property using Transitionals library

Tags: c#, wpf, transition

I am trying to incorporate the Transitionals library into my window.

I am going to use two transitions:
If button one is pressed the transition is going to be the ExplosionTransition.
If button two is pressed the transition is going to be the RotateTransition to the left.
If button two is pressed again the transition is going to be the RotateTransition to the right.

XAML:

```
<transc:TransitionElement x:Name="TransitionBox" Transition="{Binding TransitionToUse}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private Transition explosion_transition = new ExplosionTransition();
private Transition rotate_transition = new RotateTransition();
```

What I am wondering is how do you set the direction property for rotate_direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize like so:

```
private RotateTransition rotate_transition = new RotateTransition();
```

instead of in the question places it into a Transition object. Then you can access the individual transitions properties, like so:

```
rotate_transition.Direction = RotateDirection.Right;
TransitionToUse = rotate_transition;
```